# "External" Lawvere-Tierney Topologies?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, topos-theory

Suppose I have a map $j : \text{Sub}(1) \to \text{Sub}(1)$ from subterminal objects of a topos to themselves which satisfies analogous axioms to those of a Lawvere-Tierney topology, namely $j(1) = 1$, $j(a \wedge b) = j(a) \wedge j(b)$, $a \leq j(a)$ and $jj(a) \leq j(a)$. I'm having trouble defining what the closure of a subobject would be in terms of such a $j$. Is there a way to define $j$-sheaves for this, or to upgrade it into a bona fide LT-topology?

Comment: @Slade: This identity, $j(j(a)) = j(a)$, indeed holds for any Lawvere-Tierney topology, by exactly the proof you've given.

Comment: @David: With just a few seconds of thought, I'm pessimistic that your question admits a positive answer. It's true for localic toposes (toposes of sheaves over a locale) of course, since there the global elements of $\Omega$ tell you everything there is to know.

Comment: @Ingo That's what I thought as well, but I wondered if I wasn't being sufficiently clever.

Comment: I believe there exist toposes where $\mathrm{Sub} (1)$ has only two elements but non-trivial subtoposes nonetheless exist – in which case the answer to the original question is no.

Comment: @Zhen Ah thanks, that would do it.